# mysql error in ruby on rails new app database unknown

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

i have installed ruby on trails with mysql.

i installed mysql using command

```
 sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

A promt appears to ask for password, I set it to 1234 and again a promt to confirm the password appears.

I also installed the mysql2 gem using

```
gem install mysql2
```

and created a new rails app using

```
rails new app -d mysql
```

The new app was created successfully but when I start the server with `rails server` and open `http://localhost:3000` an error occurred:

```
unknown database
```

The whole stacktrace is given below

```
mysql2 (0.3.14) lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `connect'
mysql2 (0.3.14) lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `new'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:18:in `mysql2_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/home/sana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/home/sana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__695031866633904995__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/sana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/sana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/sana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

where is the error??

`config/database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: mysqltestapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 1234
  host: 127.0.0.1
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the error message is something similar to

> error occured unknown database

It means the database doesn't exist. Make sure you created it in MySQL (Rails does not create it automatically).

```
mysql -e 'create database mysqltestapp_development;'
```

If the app is not new, you should also load the schema.

```
rake db:schema:load
```

Comment: thank you so much you save my time i am beginner. God bless you

Comment: i could thumb up but cant find how to approve .. i think i have no such privilage